# Delete Statement Query Tuning

Tags: sql-server

I have the following delete query running and it's killing the memory
:

[image]

```
delete from dbo.programselected where id=@p0
```

This is the execution plan

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does "killing the memory" mean exactly? Can you [post the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: Have you considered indexing the id column to negate the clustered index scan?

Comment: Since the command is `DELETE FROM ProgramSelected WHERE Id=@P0`, and all of this work is being done against the `CoursePrerequisiteAssignment` table, what is the relationship between these tables. It is obvious that there is a Foreign Key relationship with an ON DELETE CASCADE, but what are these prereq. records, and why isn't there a straightforward FK relationship? What, exactly, are these two tables *doing* to each other?